# info about Sqlite Database using android studio

Tags: android

As SQlite database is local by downloading same app on multiple devices.if i insert some data using sqlite database so it will be shown on other device?let me know wating for response.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

> SQLite is an in-process library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine

SQLite database is local. Its associated with single application on single device only. You can't even access other application's sqlite db if that application not exposing it.

You need to use **remote database** for to share data between devices. Like **mysql**. You can checkout **Firebase Firestore** for quick implementation